# Isomorphism of Group with the Image of the Group - Fraleigh p. 82 Lemma 8.15

Tags: group-theory, intuition, proof-verification, visualization

I found multifarious duplicates that I listed at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/631364/53934.

[image]

I edged the purple part because my answer proves it more efficiently. 
I remember that any function $f: A -> f(A)$ is always onto but I misread. Sorry. Hence I removed original question (1.).

(2.) My answer presupposes a group homomorphism, but the statement of the Lemma here presupposes $\phi$ is a one-to-one function. Where does Fraleigh prove $\phi$ is a homomorphism? Where does an isomorphism crop up from? And why presuppose $\phi$ is a one-to-one function?

(3.) Is this written execrably? Hence can I use my answer instead to prove this Lemma?
Do I just need to add the presupposition $\phi$ is bijective?

**Update Jan. 14 2014:** From MJD's exquisite answer, I think the answer to this question (3.) is that I only need to add that $\phi$ is injective [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/631364/53934) if I want to use that to prove this. Perfect?

(4.) What's the intuition? Is there a picture for this?

Comment: What is $\phi[G]$?

Comment: $\phi[G]$ is the range of $\phi$ when applied to the domain $G$. Any function is onto its range, because that's what the range is.

Comment: @MJD: This is what I wanted to point out.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was directed at OP, not at you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, notice that Fraleigh does *not* claim that $\phi$ is a map of $G$ *onto* $G'$, as you said.  He only claims that it is onto $\phi[G]$. This is a weaker statement because $\phi[G]$ may be a proper subset of $G'$.

1. 
I don't think a long explanation will make this any clearer than my comment above, that any function is onto its own range because that's what the range is.  But what the heck.  $\phi[G]$ is defined as  $$\phi[G] = \{ \phi(x)\mid x\in G\}$$ which is actually shorthand for $$\phi[G] = \{ y\mid\text{there is some $x\in G$ such that $\phi(x)=y$} \}.$$  We want to show that $\phi$ is onto $\phi[G]$.  This means we want to show that every $y$ in $\phi[G]$ is the image of some $x\in G$ under the mapping $\phi$.

That is for each $y\in \phi[G]$, we want to show that there is some $x\in G$ such that $\phi(x) = y$.

But that is *exactly* the definition of $\phi[G]$ that I quoted above.

---

2. Fraleigh supposes that $\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$. This is the important property of a homomorphism. A homomorphism is just a mapping between two groups that satisfies that condition.  He has two groups, $G$ and $G'$, and $\phi$ is a mapping between them that by hypothesis satisfies the condition.  So $\phi$ is a homomorphism of $G$ into $G'$.

---

3. This is a matter of opinion.  But I did not find it unclear.

---

4. I don't know what you mean by "picture". The point of the theorem is that **a one-to-one homomorphism from $G$ to $G'$  is like locating a copy of $G$ inside of $G'$**.  Does that help?

If you are still confused, I suggest you try some small examples to see how it works.  For example, let $G = Z_2, G' = Z_8,$ and $\phi(x) = 4x$.  Then $\phi[G] = \{ 0, 4 \}$.  And under mod-8 addition, $\{0 , 4\}$ is indeed a subgroup of $Z_8$, one that behaves just like $Z_2$.

Or consider $G=Z_4$ again, and $G'$ is the nonzero complex numbers under multiplication.  Take $\phi(n) = i^n$. Then you can verify that $\phi(a + b) = \phi(a)\cdot \phi(b)$.  $\phi[G] = \{ i, -i, -1, 1 \}$, and we have found a copy of $Z_4$ inside the complex numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that if we have a map $f\colon E\rightarrow F$ then $f\colon E\rightarrow f(E)$ is surjective.

The hypothesis:
$$\phi(xy)=\phi(x)\phi(y)$$
means that $\phi$ is homomorphism and if $\phi$ is one-to-one hence since $\phi\colon G\rightarrow \phi(G)$ is onto so it's bijective and then an isomorphism.